# Does placing Civic buildings further away increase traffic?

Tags: simcity-3000

I know that placing utilities (water, power plants etc) further away from the general city is not only a valid tactic - it's generally **encouraged**, because who wants to live next to a coal power plant? - or get their drinking water from the creek running right next to heavy industry?

Obviously utilities buildings connect to the greater city via power lines/water pipes, so they don't increase traffic - in fact they're quite happy to chug along by themselves, with no transport interaction whatsoever.

But what about civic buildings, like schools, libraries and hospitals? I don't assume it's any more *beneficial* having them further away (I think they generate a positive aura).

**But does having them on the other side of the map increase traffic?**

Will the Sims 'simulate' the long commute to get to school or visit grandma in hospital? or do they not care WHERE they're placed (so long as they're placed)?

Comment: If I recall, these buildings have a radius, and to have any kind of effect they have to be built close to residential areas.  I don't *think* that traffic routes to these buildings, although they do for some (ie, the stadium).

Comment: @agent86 - Yes, I think the radius has (at the very least) an effect on aura as I mentioned. However, for example take schools- I don't think the schools go without students the further you place them away - which means the students have to be coming from somwehere - their number is most likely a thin-air calculation based on total population. But my question is whether or not the distance between Residential addresses and the school have an effect on the traffic simulation logic.